# draw contour with cv2.threshold() function

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, contour

I am testing the [cv2.threshold()](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html) function in with different values but I get each time unexpected results. So this means simply I do not understand the effect of the [parameter](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold):

- maxval

Could someone clear me on this ?

For example, I want to draw the contours of this star following the white color:

[image]

Here is what I got:

[image]

From this code:

```
import cv2    
im=cv2.imread('image.jpg') # read picture

imgray=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # BGR to grayscale

ret,thresh=cv2.threshold(imgray,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

countours,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


cv2.drawContours(im,countours,-1,(0,255,0),3)
cv2.imshow("Contour",im)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Each time I change the value of `maxval` I get a strange result that I can not understand. How can I draw the contour of this star  correctly using this function then ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to experiment with a very simple image that clearly lets you understand the various parameters. The interesting thing about the image attached below is that the grayscale value of a number shown in the image is equal to the number. E.g. 200 is written with grayscale value 200. Here is example python code you can use.

```
import cv2

# Read image
src = cv2.imread("threshold.png", cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)

# Set threshold and maxValue
thresh = 127
maxValue = 255

# Basic threshold example
th, dst = cv2.threshold(src, thresh, maxValue, cv2.THRESH_BINARY);

# Find Contours 
countours,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(dst,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Draw Contour
cv2.drawContours(dst,countours,-1,(255,255,255),3)

cv2.imshow("Contour",dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I have copied the following image from a [OpenCV Threshold Tutorial](http://www.learnopencv.com/opencv-threshold-python-cpp/) I wrote recently. It explains the various parameters with example image, Python and C++ Code. Hope this helps.

## Input Image

[image: OpenCV Threshold Test Image]

## Result Image[image]

Comment: thank you for the effort, but it does not answer my question properly

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please let me know if this helps. The best way to learn about various parameters is to take the code I have given, and change the parameters and see what happens.

Comment: thank you very much. I must read the tutorial you gave me deeply. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. In your specific example, after you convert the image to grayscale, yellow is very close to white. This may be causing some confusion for you.

Comment: I tested your solution on lot of sample images with different colors. It works in all the cases except some, such as the yellow color. Maybe you have a hint how fix this ? . You already answered my main question, I know. But if you think it is better to ask this in a separate question, just let me know. Thank you

Comment: Thank you, after searching for solutions, you brought me back to your website, where I found the resources I needed.

Answer (score 1):

well here you can use COLOR_BGR2HSV and then choose a color and the making of contour will be quite easy try it and let me know
in black and while conversion u have same color of yellow and white thats why this is not working

Answer (score 0):

For better accuracy at finding contours one may apply threshold on image as binary image tend to give higher accuracy and then use contours method.Hope this will help..!!!